CORS error accessing file in S3 from Serverless Framework deployment
I have a project based on a template using Serverless Framework to deploy a react app served from an S3 bucket.  The serverless deploy works fine, creates the CloudFormation stack, creates the S3 bucket to distribute the files, but when I load the app, it throws CORS errors, even though everything seems to be fine.
Here's the error:

Note the request URL and the Referer values.
Here's the CORS definition for the bucket (as created by the Serverless Framework) in the request URL:

Allowed origin matches the referer value in the request.
Not sure what I should be checking next.  "Block Public Access" is disabled on that bucket, as were ACLs at first.  I have since enabled ACLS and set Object Ownership to Bucket Owner Preferred.

Is the file accessible directly, i.e. when you try https://s3......amazonaws.com/.........index6f2d7164.css in the browser? Sometimes, when server returns error (like 403 here), then don't send correct CORS headers. My guess is the issue is not CORS, but the 403 here.

I think you're right.  Hitting the file directly just gives me an Access Denied HTML, and that makes more sense since the CORS stuff really does seem correct.

From the comment, the problem was not CORS but the access denied.  Thanks for the troubleshooting tips.  I added a basic policy and now it's working (and yes, the bocket uuid has changed, as I had cleaned out the old buckets and rebuilt out of desperation :) ).
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[THIS-BUCKET]-qxwuykeqwwgz/*"
        }
    ]
}

